# Респект и уважение

Tags: грамотная-речь, заимствования, жаргон

Все, надеюсь, слышали фразу "респект и уважуха"? В безсленговом варианте это звучит, как "респект и уважение".
*Respect* (англ.) переводится как "уважение", "почтение".
Получается, что говорящий это произносит фактически "масло масляное"?

Прав ли я, утверждая, что "уважение" и "почтение" — это синонимы? А это означает, что перевод сленговой фразы как "почтение и уважуха" — одно и то же.

==========================
@М_Г, @Alex_ander, @grizzly, @Jasmin - огромное человеческое спасибо за отклик и выражение собственного мнения. Я, признаться, теперь в тупике. В комментариях к ответу @Alex_ander я указал топик на форуме, где разгорелся этот спор и где я приводил свои доводы.
Подытожу, с Вашего, так сказать, позволения.))
Итак, мы имеем примерно следующее:
из четырех участников дискуссии, @Alex_ander и @М_Г полностью придерживаются точки зрения, аналогичной моей. @Jasmin высказывала несколько иные толкования, но в свете указанного мной в комментариях к ее ответу исходного контекста, откуда была взята фраза, согласилась с моими доводами. А @grizzly допускает употребление спорного выражения. Ссылаясь на собственный опыт.
Все верно, уважаемые? Я никого не обидел?
Резюмируя, получим 3:1, не считая меня.
Лично для меня идеальными являются ответы @Alex_ander и @М_Г. И не потому, что они делают меня победителем спора. Просто я тоже так считаю. Мне не важно КТО из нас (то бишь, - спорящих) окажется прав. Мне важно - КАК ПРАВИЛЬНО (точнее - уместно это словосочетание или нет). И я повторюсь, что готов извиниться перед оппонентом в случае моей неправоты.
Спор зашел из-за употребления оппонентом на форуме выражения "Респект и уважение". На что я написал, что это "масло масляное". Тогда он возразил, что под словом "респект" он понимал слово "почтение" (оно дается в качестве перевода некоторыми переводчиками, как справедливо заметил @grizzly. А я сказал, что от этого ничего не изменилось, поскольку толковые словари трактуют значение слова "почтение", как "уважение", что автоматически подтверждает мою правоту. Ссылки там есть.
Пока что большинством голосов я оказываюсь прав.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, ометьте его галочкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, это неумелое пользование сетевым жаргоном. "Респект" - транслитерация английского слова "уважение", а "уважуха" - сетевое просторечие, изредка добавляемое от непонимания происхождения первого слова. С "респектабельностью" (где доп. суффикс придаёт букв. значение "способности быть уважаемым") заимствование слова не было связано: слово побуквенно перекочевало непосредственно из англоязычных форумов в наши, с сохранением написания и форумного же значения (выражения уважения или почтения за исключительно умный и обстоятельный ответ, за оригинальную находку и т. п.).

Comment: ВСЕМ СПАСИБО! И респект! :)

Answer (score 1):

В русском языке есть фразеологизм "почёт и уважение" (см. ["Словарь фразеологических синонимов русского языка"](http://padaread.com/?book=49834&pg=217) В.П. Жукова. Он там помечен как устаревший, хотя используется в разговорной речи довольно часто. Некоторые англо-русские словари отмечают один из вариантов перевода слова "respect" как "почёт". Возможно, этим объясняется происхождение обсуждаемой фразы.

Отмечу, что в тех случаях, когда мне приходилось слышать в разговорной речи "респект и уважение" его употребление можно было в точности заменить выражением "почёт и уважение".

Comment: Точнее сказать, "было" такое _приветствие при встрече_ - рассматриваемый штамп с ним не совпадает по случаю употребления. Если попытаться в старое приветсвие буквально вникнуть, то (исходя из значения слова "почёт" как _общественного_, а не личного признания), понимать его нужно так: знаю, что вас почитают в обществе, и лично уважаю. Форумное же "респект" означает, что "после ваших действий проникся к вам уважением, считаю вас человеком знающим и отзывчивым". Поэтому нельзя отождествить одно с другим.

Comment: @Alex_ander "Форумное же "респект" означает, что "после ваших действий проникся к вам уважением..."

Мне с этим сложно согласиться. Я воспринимаю этот "респект" как обезличенное уважение мнения другого участника, но совсем не обязательно его самого. Отождествлять не нужно в любом случае, с этим сложно поспорить. Даже старое приветствие "почёт и уважение" я ни в коем случае не стал бы отождествлять с сегодняшним его употреблением — оно употребляется теперь в совершенно другом контексте.

Comment: Если респект употребляется в том значении, которое вы назвали, то это не соответствует его трактовке в англоязычных форумах, из которых оно пришло. Там это личное выражение признательности за помощь или проявленную напр. техническую компетентность.

Comment: @Alex_ander Спасибо! Я не стану спорить — Вы явно лучше ориентируетесь в этом вопросе. Ответ удалять не буду, потому что Ваши комментарии под ним могут быть полезны другим участникам.

Comment: Версия эта, конечно же, заслуживает внимания. Нельзя исключить и возможность происхождения такого выражения из старого по чисто внешним признакам. Скорее всего, его не анализируют буквально и используют как штамп, желая просто сказать собеседнику приятное :) .

Answer (score 0):

***Респект и уважуха*** ― это, вероятно,  ***респектабельность и уважение***.

Соответственно, оба слова относятся к сленгу: респектабельность ― респект, уважение ― уважуха. При этом они имеют разные оттенки значений: престижность и уважение.

РЕСПЕКТАБЕЛЬНЫЙ, [франц. respectable] 1. **Вызывающий уважение**; почтенный, солидный. Р. господин.  2. **Пользующийся высокой репутацией; престижный**. Р-ая фирма. Р. отель.

Comment: Являются ли слова "уважение" и почтение" синонимами? Обоснованно предположу, что слово "респект" пришло из английского, а не французского.

Comment: Уважение и почтение - близкие по значению слова, их можно отнести к синонимам. В русском толковом словаре нет слова "респект",  а собственная транслитерация  с английского будет также иметь значение уважения, вот и получается масло масляное. Но если "респект"  является усечением "респектабельности", то это и сленговый прием, и новое значение (престижность), отличное от уважения. Тогда это полноценное сленговое сочетание (в переводе: престиж и уважение), весьма образное и удачное.

Comment: А как это может быть усечением "респектабельности", если единственная сетевая функция слова - выражение позитивного отношения к собеседнику (за что-то)? Не объявляет же он его респектабельным - это разговор как бы "с глазу на глаз".

Comment: Не совсем поняла Вашу мысль. "Респект" может иметь значение "престижность", а это уже не "уважение", а нечто другое. То есть мы имеем не "уважение + уважение", а "престиж+уважение". Нет масла масляного в сленговом выражении.

Comment: Как эту "престижность" обратить в сетевой комплимент? У слова "респект" в форуме нет других функций.

Comment: Я, пожалуй, больше поддерживаю Alex_ander. Мы заспорили на форуме, но я, как всегда, стоящий "за справедливость" и готовый за нее идти до конца, обратился к Вам, как к профессионалам. Мы там - профессионалы несколько другого направления. (ссылка на форум без http  -  codeby.net/forum/threads/posporim.61313/ , если кому интересны мои доводы оппоненту). Я считаю себя правым. Но если Вы мне скажете, что я неправ, то я там извинюсь.

Comment: Ну тогда я не вижу разницы между респектом и уважухой,  по смыслу это одно и то же.  А разница должна быть, ищите ее в чем-то другом. Может, это смешение стилей, может, еще что. Пользователям этого сетевого термина, безусловно, должно быть виднее. А респектабельность (респект) может пониматься в Сети как известное имя, солидная репутация.

Comment: Спасибо, Jasmin!

Answer (score 0):

Не мудрствуя лукаво, нужно признать, что *респект* и *уважуха* — синонимы, а поставленные вместе они представляют собой плеоназм. Если автор употребляет такой плеоназм сознательно, для создания определенного эффекта (чтобы развеселить или эпатировать публику), то, как говорится, флаг ему в руки!

Comment: Спасибо за мнение!